# Ip routing two subnets

Tags: firewall, routing, switch, subnet

I've got two subnets

- A: 192.168.2.0/24. Within A we have got a firewall and a connection to the internet.
- B: 172.16.12.0/24.

They are connected with each other via a switch and both subnets are configured as vlans. The switch thus has a ip adress within both subnets.

- Within A I've got 192.168.2.226
- Within B it is 172.16.12.175

Now, everything works fine if I configure machines in A as follows:

- sudo ip route add 172.16.12.0/24 via 192.168.2.226

and machines in B via

- sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 172.16.12.175

Hosts on B can now access hosts on A (as well as internet hosts).

Now I'd like to remove the manual, static route on hosts on A. Instead I'd like to add the route from 192 to 172 via a rule in the firewall, such that hosts on A do not need further configuration. To this end I added an "IPv4-Unicast-Route" with the target 172.16.12.0/24 and the gateway 192.168.2.226.
Now, hosts on A can reach B:

```
> traceroute 172.16.12.4 /// running on 192.168.2.84
traceroute to 172.16.12.4 (172.16.12.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.2.254)  0.199 ms  0.219 ms  0.243 ms
 2  192.168.2.226 (192.168.2.226)  1.579 ms  1.995 ms  2.429 ms
 3  172.16.12.4 (172.16.12.4)  1.064 ms  1.044 ms  1.026 ms
```

But hosts on B cannot reach hosts on A:

```
> traceroute 192.168.2.84 //// running on 172.16.12.4
traceroute to 192.168.2.84 (192.168.2.84), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (172.16.12.175)  8.750 ms  9.058 ms  9.410 ms
 2  _gateway (172.16.12.175)  3.811 ms !H  4.551 ms !H  5.006 ms !H
```

(hosts on B can still reach internet hosts like 8.8.8.8, or hosts on A with an active manual ip route  (`sudo ip route add 172.16.12.0/24 via 192.168.2.226`))

What could be the reason for this / what am I missing regarding the configuration of the firewall? I tried adding firewall rules, that enable the access of 172 hosts to 192 but that didn't make a difference.

Edit: I shall add that the firewall has got the ip 192.168.2.254. It does route correctly to 192.168.2.226 as can be seen in the first traceroute.

Netgear switch routes as defined in the added image[netgear switch routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FWUV.png)

Comment: If the switch is running Linux, please show us the output of `ip -4 route show` ran on it. It should automatically have something very close to `192.168.2.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.226 metric 100` and it should be there once. (The ens33 is the relevant network interface and it will be different for you.)

Comment: Unfortunately it is a netgear switch with routes defined as follows. 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.2.216 (latter =ip of the switch). 172.16.12.0/24 via 172.16.12.175 (latter ip=ip of the switch). Gonna check tomorrow if i can gather further information.

Comment: I added some information in the main question.

Comment: I have a suspicion that your segment B is configured as an Isolated VLAN. This article shows how to disable it: https://kb.netgear.com/21620/How-do-I-assign-private-VLAN-type-Primary-Isolated-Community-using-the-web-interface-on-my-managed-switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following url of the board of our firewall describes the problem and a solution. https://community.sophos.com/sophos-xg-firewall/f/discussions/100540/strange-behavior-xg-forwarding-to-internal-lan-second-router

> You are experiencing asymmetric routing. Try to disable connection
> tracking and inspection by using the following commands:
>
> set advanced-firewall bypass-stateful-firewall-config add
> source_network x.x.x.x source_netmask 255.255.255.0 dest_network
> y.y.y.y dest_netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> set advanced-firewall bypass-stateful-firewall-config add
> source_network y.y.y.y source_netmask 255.255.255.0 dest_network
> x.x.x.x dest_netmask 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0):

If a host in subnet A receives a request from a host in subnet B, but doesn't have a route back to subnet B, it won't be able to send a response. In this case, the host in subnet A will try to send the response to its default gateway. If the default gateway doesn't have a route to subnet B, the response will be dropped, and the host in subnet B will never receive a response.

Comment: But the hosts on A do have a route to B. I am able to ssh from A to B. But not the other way round. Take a look at the second traceroute: I only get to the gateway which does go any further.